# Regex exclusion behavior

Tags: java, regex, string

Ok, so I know this question has been asked in different forms several times, but I am having trouble with specific syntax. I have a large string which contains html snippets. I need to find every link tag that does not already have a target= attribute (so that I can add one as needed).

`^((?!target).)*` will give me text leading up to 'target', and `<a.+?>[\w\W]+?</a>` will give me a link, but thats where I'm stuck. An example:

```
<a href="http://www.someSite.com>Link</a> (This should be a match)
<a href="SomeLink.whatever target="_blank">Link</a> (this should not be a match).
```

Any suggestions? Using DOM or XPATH are not really options since this snippet is not well-formed html.

Comment: <insert requisite "Don't parse HTML/XML with RegEx" comment here.>

Comment: <insert helpful alternative parsing technique here>

Comment: Not really a solution, but I've used the Jsoup library to parse ill-formatted HTML in the past. http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Thanks for your comment -- I don't need to parse it per-se, I simple need to add an attribute where it does not exist. The string is the result of an extensive parsing process and serves as an insert into a new HTML body - So I just need to add a simple target="_blank" where required.

Comment: Just so you know, your sample code would never render properly in the browser. Copy paste that into a test HTML file and you'll see that all it renders is this: Link (this should not be a match). (showing only text since comments don't do HTML)

Comment: ... ah yeah? the (text) was just for you to read, not for an actual browser. The real html snippets are 1500 lines long. I was merely giving an example of two links, one which should be a match, and one that shouldn't. This site does not let me post them as plain text as it thinks I'm trying to embed actual links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on doing it with Regex a pattern such as this should help...

```
<a(?![^>]*target=) [^>]*>.*?</a>
```

It's by no means 100% perfect technically speaking a tag can contain a > in places other than then end so it won't work for all HTML tags.

NB. I work with PHP, you may have to make slight syntax adjustments for Java.

Answer (score 2):

You are being wilfully evil by trying to parse HTML with Regexes. Don't.

That said, you are being extra evil by trying to do everything in one regexp. There is no need for that; it makes your code regex-engine-dependent, unreadable, and quite possibly slow. Instead, simply match tags and then check your first-stage hits again with the trivial regex `/target=/`. Of course, that character string might occur elsewhere in an HTML tag, but see (1)... you have alrady thrown good practice out of the window, so why not at least make things un-obfuscated so everyone can see what you're doing?

Comment: Ok, The purpose of this post was to look for a solution for a match that takes into account exclusions. This has many applications. I am not parsing html with regex, I have already done that with xpath and DOM. I am looking to add something simple to several lines. If the only solution is to do it with a nasty multi-tierd match, then I will do it. I was hoping someone could answer my real question which had to do with the exclusion itself. Apparently regex has no such ability (and it should). What a pain to have to do nested inverse matches.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a negative lookahead like this:
`<a(?!.*?target.*?).*?>[\w\W]+?</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this and spent about a minute writing it, but for your specific example if you can do it on the client-side, try this via the DOM:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (linkIndex=0; linkIndex < links.length; linkIndex++) {
    var link = links[linkIndex];

    if (link.href && !link.target) {
        link.target = "someTarget"
        // or link.setAttribute("target", "someTarget");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also do this via jQuery, but I thought it would be better to use plain old JS in case you weren't using jQuery.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot too. I was looking for a way to do this in DOM, perhaps this will work. Thanks!